# $mysqli->affected_rows returns 0 multi_query

Tags: php, mysql, rows-affected

I have simple code. This query works fine. It works directly through sql and from php too (changed `$mysqli->query` to `$mysqli->multi_query` to make it work from php) but it `$mysqli->affected_rows` return `0`. There are actually inserted rows and when I run it the query through heidisql it reports:

> Affected rows: 2  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 2 queries: 0.000 sec.

How am I supposed to count affected rows? What am I doing wrong?

I tried also rowCount() and didn't really helped.

```
include ("../connect.php");

$sql = "SELECT balance INTO @b
            FROM managerstock
            WHERE ID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
            INSERT INTO managerstock (`inOut`, quantity, balance)
            VALUES (1, 1, 3);";

if($result = $mysqli->multi_query($sql)){
  echo $mysqli->affected_rows;
}
```

Comment: maybe interesting? http://stackoverflow.com/a/22396503/3184785. It appears you need to accumulate the `affected_rows` when checking the `next_results`.

Answer (score 1):

Here `CALL user('param1','param2','param3','param4');`  is a stored procedure in which you can write any number of queries.

You can use `ROW_COUNT()` function to get number of rows affected, and use select statement to fetch it as output.

**Procedure**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `user`(IN `p_mode` VARCHAR(100), IN `p_id` INT(3), IN `p_name` VARCHAR(100), IN `p_contact_no` VARCHAR(100))
    NO SQL
begin
    DECLARE
        row_count int(11);

    if p_mode='update' then
        UPDATE `user` SET `name`=p_name, `contact_no`=p_contact_no WHERE `id`=p_id;
        SET row_count = ROW_COUNT();
        select row_affected as row_count;   
    end if;
end
```

**PHP Script:**

```
<?php
function execute_qry($sql){
    $fire=mysqli_multi_query($this->conn,$sql);
    $array_result= array();
    do{
        $res = array();
        if($result = $this->conn->store_result())
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                array_push($res,$row);
            }
            array_push($array_result,$res);
        }
    }while($this->conn->more_results() && $this->conn->next_result());
    return  $array_result;
}
$query  = "CALL user('update','1','hiren','1234');";
$exe_qry=execute_qry($query);
?>
```

Comment: OK, but heidi sql somehow gets that affected rows were 2, why i cant get it the same way?

Comment: hi, @M.G. i had make altaration please review it.

Answer (score -1):

First insert record then make select query

```
 include ("../connect.php");

$sql = "INSERT INTO managerstock (`inOut`, quantity, balance)
            VALUES (1, 1, 3);SELECT balance INTO @b
            FROM managerstock
            WHERE ID = LAST_INSERT_ID();";

    if($result = $mysqli->multi_query($sql)){
      echo $mysqli->affected_rows;
    }
```

Comment: Where did you get the name, password and username colums from?

Comment: I have tried in my system so please check updated @PhiterFernandes , have you DW my answer ?

Comment: I think OP is using multiple query because he will use the value of `@b` in the `INSERT` query afterwards, so the `INSERT` must come after the `SELECT`.

Comment: I have checked above query , its actually inserting record and giving 1 affected row as result,

Comment: @b has to be used in insert statement, so select has to be first